# Flaskで作ったフォームに文字列を入力するとルーティングがうまくいかない

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy, url-routing

**実現したいこと**

フォームに入力した文字列がデータベースに格納され、HTMLのページに反映されるプログラムをPython・FlaskとSQLAlchemyを使って書いています。

**困っていること**

```
$ FLASK_APP=app.py FLASK_DEBUG=true flask run
```

上記のコマンドで、現行のコードをブラウザで実行すると、フォーム画面は表示されるのですが、フォームに文字列を記入し送信すると以下のエラーが出ます。

エラー文（書いたプログラム以外のファイルに関する、実行後レスポンスの記述は省略しています）

```
File "/Users/username/Desktop/app.py", line 32, in create_todo print(sys.exc_infor())
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

**試したこと**
`import sys`とプログラム頭に追記したところ、以下のようにエラーが変化しました。
いずれにしても、解決策が分からず困っています。

```
File "/Users/username/Desktop/app.py", line 32, in create_todo print(sys.exc_infor())
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'exc_infor'
```

実行しているプログラム
index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo App</title>
<style>
    .hidden{
        display:  none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/todos/create">
        <input type= "text" name="description" />
        <input type= "submit" value="Create" />
    </form>
    <div id= "error" class="hidden">Something went wrong!</div>
    <ul>
        {% for d in data %}
        <li>{{d.description}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <script>
      const descInput = document.getElementById('description');
      document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const desc = descInput.value;
        descInput.value = '';
        fetch('/todos/create', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            'description': desc,
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonResponse => {
          console.log('response', jsonResponse);
          li = document.createElement('li');
          li.innerText = desc;
          document.getElementById('todos').appendChild(li);
          document.getElementById('error').className = 'hidden';
        })
        .catch(function() {
          document.getElementById('error').className = '';
        })
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
#import sys

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://username@localhost:5432/todoapp'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'todos'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Todo {self.id}{self.description}>'

db.create_all()

@app.route('/todos/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_todo():
    error = False
    body = {}
    try:
        description = request.form.get_json()['description']
        todo = Todo(description=description)
        db.session.add(todo)
        db.session.commit()
        body['description'] = todo.description
    except:
        error = True
        db.session.rollback()
        print(sys.exc_infor())
    finally:
        db.session.close()
    if error:
        abort(400)
    else:
        return jsonify(body)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data=Todo.query.all())
```

実行環境
Flask 1.1.1
sqlalchemy　1.3.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'exc_infor'

タイポだと考えられます。
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info

ダメ: `exc_infor`
良い: `exc_info`

その他にエラーが出るなら、以下を試してください。

import文にjsonifyのインポート部分を追加してください。

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort, jsonify
```

さらに、formからget_jsonを消し、代わりに直接キーを指定するようにします。

```py
description = request.form['description']
```

コードのappの初期化コードの下に

```py
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

を追加してください。

postgresqlで動作がしなければ、postgresqlの設定を確認するか、実行確認のためにsqliteに変更してみてください。

```py
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
```

Comment: ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。タイポを修正して再度実行したところ、
フォームに文字列を入力した後の遷移ページである「http://127.0.0.1:5000/todos/created」
では以下の表示が出るようになりました。
```
Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
````

Comment: ターミナルでは、顕著なエラー分を確認できなかったのですが、以下の表示がありました。

/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:835: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '

Comment: 1. import文にjsonifyのインポート部分を追加してください。
```from flask import  Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort, jsonify```
2. ```description = request.form['description']``` と変更します。

Comment: 3. さらにコードのappの初期化コードの下に ```app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False``` を追加してください。

Comment: 4. postgresqlで動作がしなければ、postgresqlの設定を確認するか、sqliteに変更してみてください。```app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'```